# Advice installing a vent on roof

Tags: vent, ducts, exhaust-fan, roofing, shingles

Installed a new bathroom fan today and realized the ducting is way undersized. 9'x15' room and a very tiny fan with 3" ducting. I replaced it with a 110CFM Panasonic fan.

So I can't use the existing roof vent so I probably need to cut a hole in the roof.

I watched several YouTube videos and it doesnt look super difficult but I have hesitation about cutting a hole in the roof.

Anyway, can you guys recommend what type of vent and roof sealant I should use?

Also, you guys have any helpful pointers before I start?

3x 3" bathroom exhaust ducts all going to one outside vent.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there one fan that's used by the 3 exhaust vents, or are there 3 fans?

Comment: 3 different fans, each have a hose venting outside.

Comment: I faced a similar problem and having had problems with roof leakage years before I elected to go through the side of the house. That was about 12 years ago and they still work great. Because of the distance I upsided I believe to 5" and used solid metal tubing except after the transition to the smaller size to fit the fan. I did this t 4 of them and no problems. All of the exhaust vents have a back flow prevention damper.